# VB Function not firing even when AutoPostback is true

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a bit of code that I wrote that works in the testbed but not the program. Both of these programs are forked from the same project and minor changes were made each project.

What I'm trying to do is change the state of a dropdown box when a certain option is selected. Here is the working version of the project:

The VB:

```
Protected Sub dd_customer_AddTo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dd_customer.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (dd_customer.SelectedItem.Value = "Add Customer to Database...") Then
        dd_customer.Visible = False
        txt_customer.Visible = True
        lb_customer.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The ASP.NET

```
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Customer" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Customer: "></asp:Label><br />
                <div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_customer" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_customer" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDS_GetCustomers"
                    DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" Width="189px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem>Please Select Customer</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Add Customer to Database...</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_customer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="189px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_customer" runat="server" Commandname="customer" OnClick="lb_dd_click" CausesValidation="false" Visible="false">Add customer</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_customer" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dd_Customer"
                        ErrorMessage="Please Select Customer" InitialValue="Please Select Customer">Please Select Customer</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDS_GetCustomers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testlogConnectionString1 %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [name],[id] FROM [customer] ORDER BY [ID]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <br />
```

Here is the live version which is not working:

The VB

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_AddTo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim stra As String

    stra = "test"

    If (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value = "Add Customer to Database...") Then
        DropDownList1.Visible = False
        txt_customer2.Visible = True
        lb_customer.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The ASP.NET

```
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_customer" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="txt_customer" DataValueField="id" 
                        Width="189px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_AddTo">
                        <asp:ListItem>Please Select Customer</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Add Customer to Database...</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_customer2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="189px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_customer" runat="server" Commandname="customer" OnClick="lb_dd_click" CausesValidation="false" Visible="false">Add customer</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
                        ErrorMessage="Please Select Customer" InitialValue="Please Select Customer">Please Select Customer</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testlogConnectionString1 %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [txt_customer], [ID] FROM [tbl_customer] ORDER BY [ID]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <br />
```

By setting breakpoints, I was able to see that the VB function was not being reached at all, which completely baffles me. This indicates to me that it is a problem with the ASP.NET, or  settings somewhere, but I'm not sure where they could have diverged.

Something else I noticed, when I click the option I want, then click the initial option, the validation briefly flashes.

Both versions have `AutoEventWireup` set to false.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

I added a test function, which worked with AutoPostback. I was able to run a function and see changes on the ASP.NET page, both before and after this event. Any ideas as to why it wouldn't work in this one spot?

Comment: I tried setting them to true and seeing if they worked, and AutoPostBack worked on the other portion of the script

Comment: Can you remove or temporarily comment out the required field validator and SQL datasource, and see if they are the interfering?